# Continuous deployment of C/C++ executable to Linux production servers

Tags: c++, linux, deployment

I wonder if there is any best practice or at least a more practical way to deploy C/C++ executable to Linux based production servers.

I have Jenkins up and running as CI server, and created a main SVN module which contains multiple svn:externals.  This module is mainly served as a pipeline of related C++ applications. (Perhaps I should post this an another question on whether svn:externals is the correct way to do it)

So the main question is the deployment steps, I am planing to make all production servers as Jenkins' slaves with parameterized config, for the purpose of building from SVN tags.  And use some scripts to copy all executables to, eg: /opt/mytools/bin in multiple production servers.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

The best deployment route is the one specified by your distribution, IMHO. That is, for debian packages, bundle your applications into .deb-files, put them into a repository and let apt-get take care of the rest. This way, you have a minimal impact on the production environment and most admins are already familiar with the deployment scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through some of the same questions, and I'm finding that [Continuous Delivery: Reliable Software Releases through Build, Test, and Deployment Automation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912) by Humble and Farley has been a good (technology agnostic) starting point - not perfect but it's pointed me in the right direction when I had no idea what to do next.

The continuous delivery book recommends setting up 'build pipelines' in which you run progressively more and more automated tests, with only the final manual tests and deploy rollback options being triggered by a real person.